# Java - what is a a prototype?

Tags: java

In a lecture on Java, a computer science professor states that Java interfaces of a class are **prototypes** for public methods, plus descriptions of their behaviors.

[image]
(Source https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-c4I3gFYe3w @8:47)

And at 8:13 in the video he says go to discussion section with teaching assistants to learn what he means by prototype.

What does "prototype" mean in Java in the above context?

Comment: There is no Java prototype keyword. He's saying prototype in the English language usage, meaning a model from which things can be made.

Comment: It comes from two greek words, "proto" meaning first, and "typ" meaning a model to be used for making copies.

Comment: "Prototype" is not a thing in Java.  He's probably referring to the [concept in C/C++/etc.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype).

Comment: first time i see the use of the word "prototype" for defining Interfaces, the term i have read in many books is "contract" as "Interfaces are the bussiness contract that your classes must implement if they of course `implements` it"

Comment: "Interface" has different meanings too. "Interface of a class" implies that he's referring to a more general concept than the interface construct in Java.

Answer (score 8):

I think the use of the word prototype in this context is unfortunate, some languages like JavaScript use something called prototypical inheritance which is totally different than what is being discussed in the lecture. I think the word 'contract' would be more appropriate.  A Java interface is a language feature that allows the author of a class to declare that any concrete implementations of that class will provide implementations of all methods declared in any interfaces they implement.

It is used to allow Java classes to form several is-a relationships without resorting to multiple inheritance (not allowed in Java).  You could have a Car class the inherits from a Vehicle class but implements a Product interface, therefor the Car is both a Vehicle and a Product.

Comment: The real "unfortunateness" is that "template" is legitimately used in CS and IT literature to mean many different things.  It is impractical to avoid using a term entirely because other people use it inconsistently.

Comment: @BeWarned, the word prototype in this context is not unfortunate as you say.  ECMAScript is one of only a few languages that use prototypal inheritance as an alternative to a class hierarchy.  The word prototype in this sense is a 'carry-over' from C, a language that strongly influenced Java.  In C (and C++, obj-c), by placing the function prototype above main(), one can call that code from Main() but have the implementation code below main(). In fact in CS , ECE, EE, and IT the english word prototype has a variety of meanings depending on the context in which its used.  It's not unfortunate!

Comment: It not that prototype is incorrect, it just might lead to confusion when these students are eventually exposed to JavaScript. People already have enough trouble grasping JavaScript OO, lets not compound it by using that word when describing Java OO. Especially when there are many other synonyms.

Comment: @BeWarned I don't understand how it could lead to confusion.  In fact, the only people that I could see getting confused are people who only know JavaScript, or perhaps has no experience with a strongly typed language. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_(Java) <- A quote <- "Interface methods are public, abstract and never final. Think of them as prototypes only; no implementations are allowed." <- Which is exactly like prototypes in C, C++, Obj-C... hell, even PHP interfaces.  Prototype was the perfect word to use in this context.  I have seen the video OP is referring to, have you?

Answer (score 4):

> What does "prototype" mean in Java in the above context?

The word "prototype" is not standard Java terminology.  It is not used in the JLS, and it is not mentioned in the [Java Tutorial Glossary](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/information/glossary.html#P).  In short there is no Java specific meaning.

Your lecturer is using this word in a broader sense rather than a Java-specific sense.  In fact, his usage matches "function prototype" as described in [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype).

---

Unfortunately, the "IT English" language is full of examples where a word or phrase means different (and sometimes contradictory) things in different contexts.  There are *other* meanings for "template" that you will come across in IT.  For instance:

- In C++ "template" refers to what Java calls a generic class or method.
- In Javascript, an object has a "template" attribute that gives the objects methods.
- More generally, template-based typing is an alternative (more dynamic) way of doing OO typing.

But the fact that these meanings exist does not mean that your lecturer was wrong to refer to interface method signatures as "templates".

Answer (score 3):

"prototype" is not the the best/right terminus to be used. `interfaces` are more like "contracts", that implementing classes have to fulfill.

The method's heads/definitions will have to be implemented in the implementing class (using `implements` keyword in the class head/class definition/`public class xy implements ...`).

I guess this naming conventions leave much room for many ideological debates.

Or the author had some sort of a mental lapsus and mapped the construct of prototypical inheritance from javascript into java in his mind somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Interfaces are not prototypes for classes in Java.

In languages like C & C++, which compiles to machine code sirectly, compiler should be aware of the nature of any identifier (variable/class/functions) before they are references anywhere in the program. That mean those languages require to know the nature of the identifier to generate a machine code output that is related to it.

In simple words, C++ compiler should be aware of methods and member of a class before that class is used anywhere in the code. To accomplish that, you should define the class before the code line where it is used, or you should at least declare its nature. Declaring only the nature of a function or a class creates a 'prototype'.

In Java, an 'interface' is something like description of a class. This defines what all methods a particular kind of class should mandatory have. You can then create classes that implements those interface. Main purpose that interfaces serve in java is the possibility that a Variable declared as of a particular interface type can hold objects of any class that implements the object.

Answer (score 2):

He tells it in `C/C++` way, let me explain, in `C++` you can define prototypes for methods at the header files of classes so that other classes can recognize these methods, also in `C` where there is no class concept, you can define prototypes at the beginning of file and then at somewhere in same file you can implement these prototypes, so that methods can be used even before their implementation is provided. So in `Java` interfaces provide pretty much same way, you can define prototypes for methods(method headers) that will be implemented by classes that implement this interface.

Answer (score 1):

*In a lecture on Java, a computer science professor states that:*

> Java **interfaces of a class** are:
>   1. are prototypes for public methods,
>   2. plus descriptions of their behaviors.

For 1. Is ok: - yes, they are prototypes for implemented public methods of a class.
 For 2. This part could be a little bit tricky. :)

- why?
- we know: interface definition (contain prototypes), but doesn't define (describe) methods behavior.
- computer science professor states: "... plus descriptions of their behaviors.". This is correct only if we look inside class that implements that interface (interface implementation = prototype definitions or descriptions).

> Yes, a little bit tricky to understand :)

*Bibliography:*
[Definition vs Description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Description)
[Context-dependent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-dependent)
[Name visibility - C++ Tutorials](http://goo.gl/yPV5a0)

---

*ExtraWork:*

**Note: not tested, just thinking! :)**

C++:

```
// C++ namespace just with prototypes: 
// could be used like interface similar with Java?
// hm, could we then define (describe) prototypes?
// could we then inherit namespace? :)

namespace anIntf{
   void politeHello(char *msg);
   void bigThankYou();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Prototypes provide the signatures of the functions you will use
within your code. They are somewhat optional, if you can order
your code such that you only use functions that are previously
defined then you can get away without defining them

Below a prototype for a function that sums two integers is given.

```
int add(int a, int b);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this question because i have the same impression as that teacher.

In early C (and C++ i think) a function, for example "a" (something around lexic analysis or syntactic, whatever) can not be called, for example inside main, before it's declaration, because the compiler doesn't know it (yet).

The way to solve it was, either to declare it before it's usage (before main in the example), or to create a prototype of it (before main in the example) which just specifies the name, return values and parameters; but not the code of the function itself, leaving this last one for wherever now is placed even after it's called.

These prototypes are basically the contents of the include (.h) files

So I think is a way to understand interfaces or the way they say in java "a contract" which states the "header" but not the real body, in this case of a class or methods